# STATIC FILES PYTHON ANYWHERE

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

When I run python manage.py collectstatic in the bash console of pythonanywhere I keep getting "python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". But I can clearly see my manage.py file in my code editor, I am a beginner in django and its pretty frustrating. If anyone has any ideas what this can possibly be, I would love your help. Thanks

[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn8Xx.png)

Comment: do you activate your virtual-env

Answer (score 2):

make sure you're running command on the same directory where manage.py file is. Use `python3 manage.py collectstatic`or `./ manage.py collectstatic`.